# Java8 : Can't get value of an Optional.of(String) return type

Tags: java, option-type, owl-api

In the context of using the OWLAPI 4.0 API, this following line of code:
`ontologyIRI = IRI.create(o.getOntologyID().getOntologyIRI().toString());`

returns the following string :
`"Optional.of(http://www.indytion.com/music/composition)".`

What I need is the sole string "http://www.indytion.com/music/composition".

I tried to declare ontologyIRI as Optional and use .get() method, .orElse(), etc. to no avail. I still have the returned string that includes the 'optional.of()' part.

My question is : How could I get the internal string?

Thank you very much for your help.

Edit : The full code the method

```
    private void LoadOntology(String ontologyPath)
    {
        OWLOntologyManager man = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
        OWLOntology o;

        File ontologyFile = new File(ontologyPath);
        Optional<IRI> ontologyIRI;
        try {

            o = man.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(ontologyFile);
            ontologyIRI = Optional.of(IRI.create(String.valueOf(o.getOntologyID().getOntologyIRI()).toString()));
            System.out.println("Ontology IRI is: " + ontologyIRI.get());
        } catch (OWLOntologyCreationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

The System.out.println() returns exactly this string:
"Ontology IRI = Optional.of(http://www.indytion.com/music/composition)"
```

Comment: Please be more explicit with "to no avail": show what your code looks like and what it does or why you can't run it. Both `.get()` and `.orElse()` should work.

Comment: does `o.getOntologyID().getOntologyIRI()` return the `Optional`?

Comment: @JoachimSauer I believe OP is getting `Optional.of(http://www.indytion.com/music/composition)` verbatim as String from the response.

Comment: That's one guess, but since `IRI.create` is documented to return a `IRI`, so if it returns that literal String, then something has gone wrong. That's why OP should really show us some code and not just describe the code.

Comment: Hard to tell what exactly the OP is using, but if it is [this `getOntologyIRI()`](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/blob/d93bce25e9ac24ba5d743219014153d01c5cf4db/api/src/main/java/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLOntologyID.java#L165) then the whole thing of `IRI.create(o.getOntologyID().getOntologyIRI().toString())` is completely pointless because `o.getOntologyID().getOntologyIRI().get()` would be enough

Comment: @JensBaitinger Yes, the method call to ...create() returns the string.

Comment: @ThomasKläger You have a point, I will try this but in any case, I need to instantiate individuals, hence create IRI for them. I still have the Optional.get() issue. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: `IRI` instances are immutable, so I don't see a point in trying to convert an `IRI` into a String just to create another `IRI` that is basically the same IRI.

Comment: @ThomasKläger Your proposition "o.getOntologyID().getOntologyIRI().get()" still returns the same string: "Optional.of(http://www.indytion.com/music/composition)". I can't figure out what's wrong since the type of the variable ontologyIRI is not defined as Optional<IRI>, simply IRI.

Comment: @François-XavierTalgorn: the code you showed does not prove that statement of yours and I highly suspect it is wrong (simply because the code you posted demonstrates a lack of understanding of how strings, optionals and apparently IRIs interact). Can you post the **exact** code that demonstrates the output you claim in your last comment?

Comment: @JoachimSauer You're right. Sorry for the lack of precision. Hopefully, my editing and comments should precise my question.

Answer (score 1):

Use .get() instead of toString()

```
//Returns 'Optional[example]'
Optional.of("example").toString();
    
//Returns 'example'
Optional.of("example").get();
```

Comment: I tried .get(), but the returned string is still "Optional.of(...)".

Answer (score 1):

*Short answer*: Replace

```
Optional.of(IRI.create(String.valueOf(o.getOntologyID().getOntologyIRI()).toString()));
```

with

```
o.getOntologyID().getOntologyIRI().get();
```

*Longer answer*: you're doing an awful lot of back-and forth that's pointless at best and actively harmful in some cases:

In no particular order:

- others have already commented that `IRI` instances are immutable, so creating a new one from an existing one is kind of pointless (if harmless).
- calling `Optional.of()` if you don't intend to actually return an `Optional` is almost always a bad idea.
- `String.valueOf()` is used to get a string-representation of some value and is *usually* most useful for debugging, but should not be relied on to fully round-trip everything about an object (the same applies to `toString()`.

So basically what you're left with is this:

1. `o.getOntologyID().getOntologyIRI()` gives you an `Optional<IRI>`
2. you want an `IRI`.
3. [`Optional::get`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#get()) returns the value contained in the optional, if one exists, so you simply need to call `get()`

If, however the `Optional` is empty (i.e. there *is no* underlying value) then `get()` will throw a `NoSuchElementException`. This might or might not be what you want. To work around this either call `isPresent()` before calling `get()` to check if a value exists or use any of the multitude of other accessor methods, some of which have "built-in checks" in a way.

Comment: At all, I just noticed that the OWLAPI method ...create() returns a
@Nonnull 
public com.google.common.base.Optional<org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.IRI>.
Since I don't know the difference between the two Classes (Java.util.Optional /  com.google.common.base.Optional) I'll investigate further and ask again if necessary. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: OWLAPI 4 was released prior to java 8, so the google version of Optional was the only one available. OWLAPI 5 uses java.util.Optional.

Comment: There is no relevant difference between these optional types. If you know that it is not empty, just call `get()`. As a side note, `String.valueOf(…).toString()` makes even less sense than this answer says. It’s not even doing back-and forth…

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it seems that the problem was not the code itself. This is how the problem has been solved. But I don't understand why it has been solved :

1. I copy/paste (in the same file) the "shouldAddObjectPropertyAssertions()" example from OWLAPI4 examples -> This example code runs OK (but does not use the getOntologyID() method as I do).
2. Change SDKs to another minor version '1.8.0_61'
3. Change again with initial and desired SDK '1.8.0_131'
4. Invalidate caches and restart the IDE

Problem solved. The exactly same code :

```
ontologyIRI = o.getOntologyID().getOntologyIRI().get();
System.out.println("Ontology IRI is: " + ontologyIRI);
```

Now returns the expected string value : "http://www.indytion.com/music/composition" and not "Optional.of(http://www.indytion.com/music/composition)" anymore.

If someone can explain why it has been fixed, I would be very glad.

Thank you again for your help.